# Windows Phone 8.1 PickerFlyout (TimeSpanPicker)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I need TimeSpanPicker (not TimePicker) in my Windows Phone 8.1 App..
All toolkits contains TimeSpanPicker working only on Windows Phone 8..

I search into new 8.1 API and I found PickerFlyout but i cant customize it, has anyone idea how can I do this?

I fount this code:

```
var pf = new PickerFlyout();
var tb = new TextBlock { Text = "my flyout textblock", FontSize = 20 };
pf.Content = tb;
pf.ConfirmationButtonsVisible = true;
await pf.ShowAtAsync(targetFrameWorkElement);
```

Comment: What is the problem here? Does the TextBlock not show up?

Comment: it show but i want to customize it like TimeSpanPicker, textbox show only title

Comment: Well you have to create your own TimeSpan type picker if you want to choose a TimeSpan. MS is in the middle of deprecating all WinPhone APIs and moving over to WinRT APIs. This means that previous WinPhone controls are being deprecated, and may or may not exist in future versions (not a thing on WinRT or in the middle of moving over). It's a frustrating time, but you should try to make the missing tools yourself.